# How does iptables masquerading allow to access a different local subnet?

Tags: networking, unix, router, ip, iptables

My Linksys router (IP **192.168.1.1** inside a /24 subnet) is connected to my ADSL modem (IP **10.0.0.138** inside a /24 subnet) to establish an internet connection via PPPoE. To be able to access the modem's webinterface from one of the PCs that are connected to the router, the following commands need to be executed on the router:

```
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev vlan1 brd +
iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -o vlan1 -d 10.0.0.138 -j MASQUERADE
```

As far as I understood this is necessary because the router would otherwise assume the IP 10.0.0.138 to be an external address since it is not part of its own 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.

But what are these two lines doing exactly? The first one seems to assign a second IP address to the vlan1 interface (which is basically the router's WAN port). The second one apparently modifies the source address of outgoing IP packets. But isn't that exactly what any home router does by default? By using `iptables -t nat -L` I found that there is already a rule:

```
target      prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Now the second commands adds

```
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.138
```

to this table, but isn't this only a more specific version of the above rule and therefore redundant?

It would be great if someone could explain me the details of what's going on here exactly!

---

Output of `ip route`:

```
87.186.225.71   dev ppp0   proto kernel  scope link  src [my public IP]
10.0.0.0/24     dev vlan1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1
192.168.1.0/24  dev br0    proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
127.0.0.0/8     dev lo                   scope link
default via 87.186.225.71 dev ppp0
```

Output of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo:  mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope host lo
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:10:2f:fe:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:10:2f:fe:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: vlan0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue
    link/ether 00:13:10:2f:fe:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: vlan1:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue
    link/ether 00:13:10:2f:fe:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global vlan1
6: br0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue
    link/ether 00:13:10:2f:fe:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global br0
...
23: ppp0:  mtu 1492 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 3
    link/ppp
    inet [my public IP] peer 87.186.225.71/32 brd [my public IP] scope global ppp0
```

Comment: MOREINFO about your setup is needed. please show the output of `ip addr`, `routel` and `iptables-save`.

Comment: Your modem is problably configured with only the `10/24` subnet routed through its LAN port, so if you try to access your router with a source address in `192.168.1.0/24`, it may try to route the response to its WAN port or discard the packet. Except to access the internet, your router probably already have an address in the `10/24` range, so that's a bit strange. The `MASQUERADE` rule also seems unnecessary at first glance, but `iptables -L` is known to hide some options that can make a huge difference.

Comment: I'm running a modified Tomato firmware which does neither include `routel` nor `iptables-save`, sorry. I don't think that my router already has an IP in the modem's `10.0.0.0/24` range to access the internet, though, because PPPoE is located below the IP layer and therefore does not use any IPs. I found this [link](http://beusergroup.co.uk/technotes/index.php?title=Dd-wrt#Routing_the_traffic_out_of_the_LAN) which tries to explain. What's still unclear is which IP is copied into the outgoing packets by the `MASQERADE` rule since the `vlan1` has multiple IPs now (`192.168.1.1` and `10.0.0.1`).

Comment: apparently, `MASQUERADE` chooses the address whose subnet contains the next hop's address, or something like that (Not sure why it doesn't just pick up the preferred source address). So that mean `10.1` for `10/24`. If `routel` is not available, show the output of `ip rule` and `ip route`. Also show the output of `iptables -t nat -S` and `iptables -S` to replace `iptables-save`

Comment: Unfortunately, `ip rule` doesn't work and the `-S` argument of `iptables` is not known. The firmware contains iptables v1.3.8 which is quite old I assume. Maybe at least `ip route` and `ip addr` are of any help, so I added the outputs to the main post.

Comment: `iptables -nvL` and `iptables -t nat -nvL` might bring more information here. The counter for the second nat rule should be zero. Then it is never used as intended. Additionally you should not use `MASQUERADE` but `SNAT` as you know the own (static) IP for a better performance. Can the router access the modem (ping or http tunnel through ssh) without the additional rules you mentioned?